# Send email from angular 2 app

Tags: php, email, angular

Im looking for a way to send an email from a angular 2 application. The solution i've considered so far is to have a php backend that send the email and then get the email content from angular 2 through a http post request.

Does this sound like it's possible? 
Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Any help and tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: You are right, that is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

***Server is supposed to send emails.*** 
What you can do is, you can set `To,From,Body,Subject` fields from/by Angular2 (probably from ***Angular2 forms***) and send it to ***PHP server*** through ***HTTP Client*** of Angular2. You can certainly check validation (if any required) at Angular2 side.
By the way there is nothing new with Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this.  If you are working on a simple project, and don't need a backend server for much else; I would recommend an email service such as Mailchimp or Mandrill.  They have an api that you can connect with to do lots of different things (Templates, schedules, bulk, etc..).  I have used Mandrill in the past and it has worked very well.

Comment: Keep in mind that sending the email to Mandrill should still happen in the server otherwise you would be force to expose your API Key which is a big no-no.

Comment: I agree with this.  However, this is acceptable for development and non customer facing websites. It always depends on the use cases.